# Integrating over parameter in Bayes

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I am going over the paper "Sparse Bayesian Learning and Relevance Vector Match" by Michael Tipping. There is one equality there which I do not fully understand.
He states:

$$p(t | \alpha, \sigma^2) =  \int p(t|w,\sigma^2)p(w|\alpha)dw$$

I would understand it if it would be:

$$p(t | \alpha, \sigma^2) =  \int p(t|w,\sigma^2, \alpha)p(w | \alpha, \sigma^2)dw$$

Does this means that the conditional $\alpha$ can be placed in either side without assuming anything about it. I do not understand why.

Thanks

Comment: Your expression is the correct one. Perhaps in the context he's working in we have $p(t|w,\sigma^2,\alpha)=p(t|w,\sigma^2)$ and $p(w|\alpha,\sigma^2)=p(w|\alpha)$?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in the previous question: [A confusing excersice about Bayes' rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211495/a-confusing-excersice-about-bayes-rule%3E).

As $\omega$ is conditional only on $\alpha$, then $p(\omega | \alpha, \sigma^2) = p(\omega | \alpha)$.

Then $p(t | \omega, \alpha, \sigma^2) = p(t | \omega, \sigma^2)$ because the $\alpha$ is implicit inside the $\omega$.